# Can I use Xcode Test Navigator for EarlGrey tests?

Tags: unit-testing, ios-ui-automation, earlgrey

Like the following:

[image: Sample Xcode Test Navigator Screenshot]

[Xcode Test Navigator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-test_navigator/Recipe.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [From the FAQ:](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/master/docs/faq.md)

> **Can I use Xcode Test Navigator?**
>
> Yes. EarlGrey supports **Test Navigator** out-of-the-box.